# error TS2554: Expected 0-1 arguments, but got 2

Tags: typescript

I don't get why the compiler five me such an error message. 
I am trying to insert a lambda as an argument to a function and thereby get an error.
Thanks in advance to all the helpers!

```
const allOperationSymbols = ['+', '-', '/', '*', '^'] as const;
export type OperationSymbol = typeof allOperationSymbols[number];

type OperationMap = Map<OperationSymbol, (Left: Value, Right: Value) => Value>;
```

```
export class Type {

    private definedOperations: Set<OperationMap>;

     public appendOperation(operationMap: OperationMap) {
        this.definedOperations.add(operationMap);
    }
}
```

```
class Types {
    private value: Array<Type> = [];

    public appendType(type: Type) {
        this.value.push(type);
    }

    public addInteger() {
        let Integer: Type;
        Integer = new Type('Integer', new Set());

        const operationMap = new Map('+', /*here is the error*/ (Left: Value, Right: Value): Value => {
        const LeftNumber = Number(Left);
        const RightNumber = Number(Right);
        const areIntegers = Number.isInteger(LeftNumber) && Number.isInteger(RightNumber);
        if (LeftNumber != NaN && RightNumber != NaN && areIntegers) {
            return new Value((Number(Left) + Number(Right)).toString(), Integer);
        }
    });

    Integer.appendOperation(operationMap);

    this.appendType(Integer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Expected 0-1 arguments, but got 2

You are using the `Map` constructor wrong (and TypeScript is pointing it out).

Your usage:

```
new Map('+', function);
```

The `Map` constructor in JavaScript takes nothing (0 arguments) or an array (1 argument) of `key,value` tuples. e.g. correct usage (1 argument version):

```
 new Map([
   ['+', function]
 ]);
```

## More

See : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/Map

Answer (score 1):

There are a several issues with your code.

1. `private definedOperations: Set<OperationMap>;` - has not initializer.

Possible fix: `private definedOperations: Set<OperationMap> = new Set()`

2. `Type` class does not expects any constructor argument, whereas you are trying to pass two:  `'Integer'` and  `new Set()` here `new Type('Integer', new Set());`
3. `Map` expects **one** iterable argument, like here: `new Map([['key','value']])`.
   It means that if you want to create new instance of `Map` with some initial key/value pair, you should do it like here:

```
     const operationMap: OperationMap = new Map([['+', (Left: Value, Right: Value): Value => {
            const LeftNumber = Number(Left);
            const RightNumber = Number(Right);
            const areIntegers = Number.isInteger(LeftNumber) && Number.isInteger(RightNumber);
            if (LeftNumber != NaN && RightNumber != NaN && areIntegers) {
                return new Value((Number(Left) + Number(Right)).toString(), Integer);
            }
            return new Value('default', Integer)
        }]]);
```

4. And the last one, `(Left: Value, Right: Value): Value` should always return a `Value`, whereas you are trying to return `Value` conditionaly. If your data does not meet this reuirements `LeftNumber != NaN && RightNumber != NaN && areIntegers` you should return some default `Value`.

Working code without errors:

```js
const allOperationSymbols = ['+', '-', '/', '*', '^'] as const;
export type OperationSymbol = typeof allOperationSymbols[number];

class Value {
    constructor(arg: string, type: Type) { }
}

type OperationMap = Map<OperationSymbol, (Left: Value, Right: Value) => Value>;

export class Type {

    private definedOperations: Set<OperationMap> = new Set()

    public appendOperation(operationMap: OperationMap) {
        this.definedOperations.add(operationMap);
    }
    constructor(type: string, set: Set<unknown>) { }
}

class Types {
    private value: Array<Type> = [];

    public appendType(type: Type) {
        this.value.push(type);
    }

    public addInteger() {
        let Integer: Type;
        Integer = new Type('Integer', new Set());

        const operationMap: OperationMap = new Map([['+', (Left: Value, Right: Value): Value => {
            const LeftNumber = Number(Left);
            const RightNumber = Number(Right);
            const areIntegers = Number.isInteger(LeftNumber) && Number.isInteger(RightNumber);
            if (LeftNumber != NaN && RightNumber != NaN && areIntegers) {
                return new Value((Number(Left) + Number(Right)).toString(), Integer);
            }
            return new Value('default', Integer)
        }]]);

        Integer.appendOperation(operationMap);

        this.appendType(Integer);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgGwQeQA4FMBOcoEtwDKAngLYBGICEMAvDANoDkA1IwDQyMC07nA9L0YAqQQD1GAXXjVQkKAG4AsACh0AD1QhMsKEQww0WHPjDFylWjF0YQAM3hJD2PIVIUq9MAFdyWCUuUVYAQ4CGoANUQvdBgAbxUYRJhZaEwvYCgtAAo4TABzAC4YVNwwPI5rdCKAFT10AEo4mABfFVbA5UqDDGcTAFk4VEsB1AAeJ2NXcwQOLIAZdFsoIsiEaI4AJVw8gAtlmFXoxpoAPgOo9BOAlXVNbWSQsJha-XiOpJhUTFwANxwYgAmi1K6ABExckCKBHQUHGPUmYBGZzoYHQAHcYNCoFl6ioEklUF4yAhcMB4KgMGAwfCIVkQDT%20oMiuDGahGm8Ph8oDtcBAAHRA2wg6lGCH8uAAgF0hngEb1AIfdofFJQNIZbKVIolMocCAwqEw0ZeMAAazAIDRYBO7JabTxymCoWoL3Q1A5BO%20fygMT%20ayqMAAgphsERRi7kQx-PaPoTiaTyZSAS6sprnnV2fjOVYefzfdE%20YSIDsU%20mFUl2pnPkSSWSJQCAJJgb15LA4uKVj4IGEwRvNrA1OplrO99AtzCWVEY5OMEdj3iTzEwnHy6NZ5LgaAwemi1nMmWIwYT9EwEZZehMVizBZLFYXTbbPa3v31J-RWhnd1rpIqmDXqAAOR8MgsEsQDfEweZFigFdlC-ZUN1gLZdgAoCQLoMDgIgpC9hguDvwQ%20BMHQWcsGodDUMwPleRIiC-wwrBGgAMkYmB6Mo6im1HVtsJQ8DcLwmBcHsSCljYmAAEJ0Lgf8YGYmAeLEyTWOk2SWNyYjOLHCAM1ggSPiIqAvEwMAYAXQ50CyLI2JE6CYGYViKKyHj6nqPlMgIVVSjyHEOBo-i8KVASDKMkyzIuLJGEFOAvAQKBeD8jtywkCQYMSxIaL5QZExZcBpR3WVBlS3Ss25XlMopdAqWTPyh1tZRmiAA)

P.S. Try to use `Number.isNan` instead of `RightNumber != NaN`. It is much safer. See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN)